# How to parse & index different portions of an HTML page using Tika & Lucene?

Tags: search, full-text-search, html-parsing, lucene

I have been trying to parse & index different portions of an HTML page using Lucene & Tika. For eg. I would like to index text within Title, H1, H2, A tags of a HTML page separately and provide a different boost to each of them. I am using Tika for HTML parsing and creating a Document object with the appropriate fields that need to be indexed. However I could not find anything within Tika which would help me index the tags I want right out of the box.

My code looks something like this :

```
 InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f); 
 Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser(); 
 ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
 ParseContext context = new ParseContext(); 
  context.set(HtmlMapper.class, DefaultHtmlMapper.INSTANCE); 

 try {
  parser.parse(is, handler, metadata, context);
 } finally {
  is.close();
 }

 Document doc = new Document();
 doc.add(new Field("contents", handler.toString(),
   Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

 for (String name : metadata.names()) {
  String value = metadata.get(name);

  if (textualMetadataFields.contains(name)) {
   doc.add(new Field("contents", value,
     Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
  }

  doc.add(new Field(name, value, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.YES));
 }
```

Stepping into Tika's HTML parsing code I found that it is org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlHandler class that fills up metadata object.

Do I need to write a custom HTML handler like HtmlHandler ? 
Is there some class in Tika which can parse out text within different HTML tags that one specifies ? 
Can someone please provide code samples for solutions that you propose ?

Answer (score 0):

Um. Are you using a search engine for the project for any specific reason?  I used one to search for an answer, imagine that ;-)

[A good and relevant tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-apache-tika/?ca=drs-)